# How to programatically access the datatypes available in a .net application

Tags: .net, linq, reflection

Short question: is there a way to access the datatypes available in .net application as a group (and hence query them with LINQ). Like this ...

```
Dim myType = from l in myapplication.availabledatatypes where l.name="name of type I want" select l
```

Longer explanation:
I'm trying to move lots of old records from tables into identical 'archive' tables with Linq to SQL. As a part of that process, I need to select records from the live table and convert them to  the (identical) archive type. I'm trying to do this cleanly with a single method that can be used for all the different table/archive table pairs by using reflection, following this excellent guide
http://michaelmerrell.com/2010/08/converting-a-linq-object-to-a-similar-object/

My conversion method will take an input of type object and convert it to an output of type object, which I then plan to cast to the required output type in the method that calls the converting method. I am able to get the property of datacontext which has the same name as the type I want to convert to, but I can't seem to programatically pull the type with the same name.

```
Dim typeIamLookingFor as propertyInfo= from l in mydatacontext.getproperties where l.name.contains("archive") and l.name.contains(input.gettype.name) select l
```

How do I pick, from the types available in my namespace, the one whose name equals that of typeIamLookingFor. Obviously .getType returns the type PropertyInfo, but what I really want is the type with the name = typeiamlookingfor.name

**Edit**
Thanks for suggestions. Type.GetType gets me closer, but compiler now saying Object Must Implement IConvertible. I am going to investigate this different error and accept this answer.

```
Dim output as object
Dim typeName as string = "namespace." & inputObject.gettype.name & "_Archive"
output = output = Convert.ChangeType(output, Type.GetType(typeName))  //generates error: Object Must Implement IConvertible
```

Comment: I wouldn't try to find out all of the types available, that seems like an overkill. Instead, just try to instantiate the type and if you have it it will work, if you don't then you're going to get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating your solution.  Based on your description, you probably just need `Type.GetType()`:

```
Type typeIamLookingFor = Type.GetType("archive." + typeName)
```

Is there more to it?